# How to compare one element with other elements within the list

Tags: python, list

I have a list `x = [a, b, c, d]`.

I want to compare:

1. First element `a` with `b`, `c` and `d`.
2. Second element `b` with `a`, `c` and `d`.
3. Third element `c` with `a`, `b` and `d`.
4. Fourth element `d` with `a`, `b` and `c`.

This is the method I have used but it's not working as I want:

```
for i in len(x):
    for j in range(i+1, len(x)):
        Compare(x[i], y[j])
```

Comment: What result are you looking to achieve?

Comment: `for i in range(len(x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    for el in x[:i] + x[(i+1):]:
        print("Compare {} with {}".format(x[i], el))
        # or: Compare(x[i], el)
"""
Output:
Compare a with b
Compare a with c
Compare a with d
Compare b with a
Compare b with c
Compare b with d
Compare c with a
Compare c with b
Compare c with d
Compare d with a
Compare d with b
Compare d with c
"""
```

As a function:

```
def exclusive_compare(l, comparefun):
    return [comparefun(l[i], el) for el in l[:i] + l[(i+1):] for i in range(len(l))]

exclusive_compare(l, lambda x, y: (x, y))

Out[9]: 
[('a', 'b'),
 ('a', 'c'),
 ('a', 'd'),
 ('b', 'a'),
 ('b', 'c'),
 ('b', 'd'),
 ('c', 'a'),
 ('c', 'b'),
 ('c', 'd'),
 ('d', 'a'),
 ('d', 'b'),
 ('d', 'c')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good place to use [*itertools*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

```
for i in list(itertools.permutations(x, 2)):
    print("Compare {0} with {1}".format(*i))

"""    
Compare a with b
Compare a with c
Compare a with d
Compare b with a
Compare b with c
Compare b with d
Compare c with a
Compare c with b
Compare c with d
Compare d with a
Compare d with b
Compare d with c
"""
```

If `a == b` and `b == a` then you can use combinations to get distinct pairs:

```
for i in list(itertools.combinations(x, 2)):
    print("Compare {0} with {1}".format(*i))

"""
Compare a with b
Compare a with c
Compare a with d
Compare b with c
Compare b with d
Compare c with d
"""
```

Answer (score -1):

A silly mistake, you forgot to print hte comparison. Here is the solution:

```py
For i in len(x):
 For j in range(i+1, len(x)):
  print(Compare(x[i], y[j]))
```

Comment: This code doesn't result expected output, after fix these errors:  `#'int' object is not iterable (range(len(x)))`
`#name 'Compare' is not defined ("Compare")`
`#name 'y' is not defined (x[j])` the result is (_Compare a b
Compare a c
Compare a d
Compare b c
Compare b d
Compare c d_)